# ubuntu 18.04 ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk

Tags: python, matplotlib

when I use superplot_gui it comes out the error:

> Could not load matplotlib - GTK backend. 
>   Your version of matplotlib may not be compiled with GTK support.
>   Reinstalling matplotlib may fix this problem - see README or user manual for instructions

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "super_gui.py", line 32, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkagg.py", line 12, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import (
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 38, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gdk import RendererGDK, FigureCanvasGDK
  File "/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gdk.py", line 29, in <module>
from matplotlib.backends._backend_gdk import pixbuf_get_pixels_array
ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk
```

I did not get this problem before I upgrade my ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

I have tried the solution in other related question but they does not work.

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using? How did you install it?